# Passing number of parameters vs passing map, which is better while writing a method?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, collections, hashmap

While writing a method, what is better calling a method with number of parameters or creating a Map and passing it as 1 parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also consider using an argument class with a builder.

```
myMethod(MyArgument.newBuilder().withFirstArg("arg1").build());
```

- It is long and tedious
- You are safe against maps having misspelt keys
- You can mandatory and optional parameters
- Your method is cleaner as it accesses methods directly instead of having to check if the map containsKey

Alternatively, you could try using the fluent interface.

```
myMethod("arg1").invokeWith("arg2").anotherOne("arg3").andOneMore("arg4").andTheLastOne("arg5");
```

Answer (score 1):

If your method requires

- dynamic number of arguments (e.g. which are based on the user input), then a Map is a good solution
- fixed number of arguments and there are many of them (e.g. more than 5) then probably it means it does too much and should be split into a few methods